# Mongodb can I structure this data

Tags: python, mongodb

Basically I am designing and developing an application in Python that each night executes and takes a website and a list of keywords and queries the Google API to obtain their position given a specific keyword.

I want to use a none sql approach and using objects that Mongodb offers this seems like the best approach however I'm confused about how to structure the data inside the database.

Each night new data will be generated this will contain 50 keywords and their positions this I presume will be stored inside its own object and will be able to be identified by a specific url.

So therefore will it be possible to query the database given a url and use a data range of say the past 30 days or 60 days? I'm confused if I will be able to fetch all of objects back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main requirement for that structure will be ability to query on daily  basis.

so let say we have a website www.stackoverflow.com and our **X** keywords.
The basic document shape could look like that:

```
{
    _id : objectId, // this have timestamp
    www : "www.stackoverflow.com",
    rankings : [{
            "key1" : "val1"
        }, {
            "key2" : "val2"
        }
    ],

}
```

then, if we want to see a ranking history per `key1`, we can use aggregation framework to query:

```
db.ranking.aggregate(
    [{
            $unwind : "$rankings"
        }, {
            $match : {
                        "rankings.key1" : { $exists : true}    
            }

        }
    ])
```

and response will be similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584dbe04f4ce077869fee3dc"),
    "www" : "www.stackoverflow.com",
    "rankings" : {
        "key1" : "val1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584dbe07f4ce077869fee3dd"),
    "www" : "www.stackoverflow.com",
    "rankings" : {
        "key1" : "val1"
    }
}
```

seek more about grouping in aggregation framework to uncover  power of mongo!

Comment: thanks for the reply. The "rankings" will need to have a date time stamp on them though I will need to query over the past 30 days for example! Also using the structure how easy would it be to add more keys to the object?

Comment: you can add more data up to document limit which is 16MB (data+(B)json overhead). And there is no limit to have own timestamps inside key values.